# How to make gridsplitters visible on load button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make my gridsplitters in a custom user control have visibility collapsed
based on when the parent control has loaded some data using a load button?  I thought that the way to do this would be to create a property dataloaded on the parent control and then set a trigger in the triggers of the usercontrol like below:

but I can't seem to get it to reference the property of the usercontrol (graphviewer).

Also, can property triggers reference other controls within the control like I did below? I am assuming either my syntax is wrong or what I am trying to do is not possible.  So Far I have only messed with a few basic properties within trigger templates when making modifications to control templates, so I don't really know whether what I am trying to do is possible.

```
  <UserControl.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="GraphViewer.DataLoaded" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="SignalNameGridSplitter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
  </UserControl.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... first add the XML Namespace of your `GraphViewer` control - something like this:

```
xmlns:YourXmlNamespace="clr-namespace:YourApplicationName.FolderNameIfApplicable"
```

Then add this into a `Style`... it has to be in a `Style.Triggers` collection because you can't use a `DataTrigger` in a `UserControl.Triggers` collection:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataLoaded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespace:GraphViewer}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="SignalNameGridSplitter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```